# Ubuntu - unable to ID AD Accounts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, active-directory, realmd

After following [this guide](http://www.wolffhaven45.com/blog/linux/join_ubuntu_workstation_windows_domain/#1),

I got to the point were it tells me to verify using ID "username"
which just straight up tells me this account does not exist.

I have been adding debian machines to the same domain without issue (also using realmd + SSSD) but this is my first ubuntu. (ubuntu server)

realm list gives me the following result:

```
Foo.Bar  
  type: kerberos  
  realm-name: FOO.BAR  
  domain-name: Foo.Bar  
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: sssd-tools
  required-package: sssd   required-package: libnss-sss  
  required-package: libpam-sss   required-package: adcli  
  required-package: samba-common-bin   login-formats: %U   login-policy:
  allow-realm-logins
```

I also noted that su does not recognize the domain and just ignores my \ resulting in:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ su foo\user
No passwd entry for user 'foouser'
```

UPDATE:

```
dig –t SRV _ldap._tcp.foo.bar | grep –A2 "ANSWER SECTION"
grep: ANSWER SECTION: No such file or directory
```

However, we checked with nslookup and nslookup can find the SRV records:

```
user@ubuntu:/home/user# nslookup
> set type=srv
> _ldap._tcp.foo.bar
Server:         172.16.0.1
Address:        172.16.0.1#53

_ldap._tcp.foo.bar service = 0 100 389 server1.foo.bar.
_ldap._tcp.foo.bar service = 0 100 389 server2.foo.bar.
_ldap._tcp.foo.bar service = 0 100 389 server3.foo.bar.
```

Comment: use `su 'foo\user'` or `su foo\\user`. A backslash is the escape character for special characters in Bash.  So you have to single-quote it or escape it with a backslash.

Comment: yes, we thought so too, this however only gets me this:  
No passwd entry for user 'foo\user'

Comment: For anyone running in to the same issue. We have looked extensively and not found anything. We currently switched everything over to Debian, which does the whole AD integration just fine. (We still had the option to do this). I am, however, still very interested in any possible solution.

Comment: @kazaamjt did you ever solve this problem? I'm going through the same with Ubuntu 18.04.6, using realm to join the domain which did work, but not searching users with id